# Qt Parameter Count Mismatch with QSQL and Bind Values

Tags: c++, qt, qsqlquery

I'm currently facing an error where I get "Parameter count mismatch" from query.lastError, my bindvalues are correct (i've tested them).

My query is:

```
QSqlQuery query(DBT);
query.prepare("SELECT Foto, Nombre, Apellido1, Apellido2, Curso, Grupo, FotoHuella FROM usuarios WHERE Nombre=:nombre1 OR Apellido1=:apellido1 OR Apellido2=:apellido2 OR Curso=:curso1 OR Grupo=:grupo1");
    query.bindValue(":nombre1", nombre, QSql::Out);
    query.bindValue(":apellido1", apellido1, QSql::Out);
    query.bindValue(":apellido2", apellido2, QSql::Out);
    query.bindValue(":curso1", curso, QSql::Out);
    query.bindValue(":grupo1", grupo, QSql::Out);
query.exec();
```

In case you where wondering here is where I set up the database:

```
QSqlDatabase DBT=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
DBT.setDatabaseName("/home/pi/FoodCircleDBT.db");
DBT.open();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to [this `QSql::ParamType` reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsql.html#ParamTypeFlag-enum), the value `QSql::Out` is for "The bind parameter is used to receive data from the database". That's not what your parameters are for. Try using `QSql::In` instead (which is the default for `bindValue`).

Comment: Exactly, or just don't use the 3rd parameter at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me: actually everything relating to the code worked perfectly but somehow my database schema went crazy when I edited it with a database program. So If you are facing this I recommend you to open the command line and checking your schema.